# What characters in Game of Thrones have been recast?

Tags: game-of-thrones, behind-the-scenes

There has been some obvious recasting in *Game of Thrones* for characters like Gregor Clegane and Daario Naharis. It also seems to be quite well known that Myrcella Baratheon was recast.

**What characters in the show have been recast?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

My answer is largely sourced from what I've seen myself from watching the show and [this wikia post](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Recast_characters). Though the order will largely follow the wikia post so I don't end up forgetting someone.

## Major Roles

#### Ser Gregor Clegane (The Mountain)

Originally played by Conan Stevens in Season 1 he was recast to Ian Whyte in Season 2 and finally to Hafþór Júlíus Björnsson for Seasons 4 to 7 (and I believe 8).

For a bit of trivia here Ian Whyte is [credited](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1480055/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) as playing White Walker #1 in the prologue to the series.

#### Daario Naharis

Was originally played by Ed Skrein in Season 3 but was recast to Michiel Huisman for Seasons 4 to 6 due to a scheduling conflict for Ed.

#### Tommen Baratheon

Played by Callum Wharry for Seasons 1 and 2 but was recast to Dean-Charles Chapman. Bryan Cogman talks about this [here](https://winteriscoming.net/2014/05/14/game-owns-bryan-cogman-returns/) but he essentially states that they wanted a more experienced actor.

For a bit of trivia here Dean-Charles originally played Martyn Lannister in Season 3 before that character was killed off.

#### Three-Eyed Raven

Was played by Struan Rodger in Season 4 in the finale and was taken over by Max von Sydow for Season 6.

#### Night King

Was originally played by Richard Brake for Seasons 4 and 5 but was recast to Vladimír Furdík for Seasons 6 and 7 (and likely 8). The new actor also played the First Man version of the character.

#### Beric Dondarrion

Was played by David Michael Scott for Season 1 in a minor role but changed to Richard Dormer for Seasons 3, 6 and 7 (also potentially 8).

## Minor Roles

#### Myrcella Baratheon

Played by Aimee Richardson for Seasons 1 and 2 but was recast to Nell Tiger Free for Seasons 5 and 6.

#### Lord of Bones

Was played by Edward Dogliani for Seasons 2 and 3 but was recast to Ross O'Hennessy for a brief appearance in Season 5.

#### Lothar Frey

Played by Tom Brooke for Season 3 and Daniel Tuite for Season 6.

#### Dickon Tarly

Was played by Freddie Stroma for Season 6 but recast to Tom Hopper for Season 7 due to a scheduling conflict.

#### Leaf

Originally played by the child actor Octavia Alexandru in Season 4 and was recast to Kae Alexander for Season 6.

#### Richard Karstark

Played by Steven Blount for Season 1 and John Stahl for Seasons 2 and 3.

#### Ghost

As mentioned in [@Möoz's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/184411/58193) the pup Ghost was played by a Northern Innuit for Season 1 and then the wolf Quigly from Season 5 and 6 (and hopefully 8).

#### Summer and Nymeria

[Andrew Simpson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1201204/) from [Instinct for Film](http://www.instinctforfilm.com/) is credited as having been involved in the show since Season 5. He is credited for Season 7 Episode 2, "Stormborn", where only Nymeria shows up. Season 6 Episode 5, "The Door", where only Summer shows up.

It is likely that Grey Wind and Shaggydog were also recast after Season 1 but I haven't found anything to confirm this yet.

---

The above mentioned wikia page lists a few "Placeholder" characters who were essentially extras and then cast into named roles later on. As such the characters weren't really recast but they are worth a quick mention.

- High Septon
- Selyse Baratheon

This page does mention Beric Dondarrion and Richard Karstark here but I disagree with the wikia here and instead think of these as actual re-castings.

---

Worth a mention are the characters that were recast from the pilot to the main production.

#### Daenerys Targaryen

Played by Tamzin Merchant and then changed to Emilia Clarke.

#### Catelyn Stark

Played by Jennifer Ehle and then changed to Michelle Fairley.

#### Illyrio Mopatis

Played by Ian McNeice and then changed to Roger Allam.

#### Gared

Played by Richard Ridings and then changed to Dermot Keaney.

#### Ser Waymar Royce

Played by Jamie Campbell Bower and then changed to Rob Ostlere.

---

An honourable mention is Grand Maester Pycelle who was originally meant to be played by Roy Dotrice. However, due to health reasons he had to pull out and we got Julian Glover instead for Seasons 1 through 6. Dotrice eventually plays Hallyne, the pyromancer in Season 2.

Comment: Would have been interesting to see Tamzin Merchant play Daenerys

Answer (score 92):

## At least eleven...

<sub>[or see the other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/184380/57310)</sub>

---

### Gregor Clegane:

Conan Stevens season 1.  Ian Whyte season 2. Hafþór Júlíus Björnsson starting season 3.

[image: Gregor S1] [image: Gregor S2] [image: Gregor S3]

---

### Myrcella Baratheon:

Aimee Richardson on seasons 1 and 2. Nell Tiger Free season 5.

[image: Myrcella S1] [image: Myrcella S5]

---

### Tommen Baratheon:

Callum Wharry season 1. Dean Charles Chapman season 4. (Fun Fact: Before Chapman was Tommen, he had already appeared as Martyn Lannister in season 3.)

[image: Tommen S1] [image: Tommen S4]

---

### Daario Narharis:

Ed Skrein season 3. Michiel Huisman starting season 4.

[image: Daario S3] [image: Daario S4]

---

### Beric Dondarrion:

David Michael Scott season 1.  Richard Dormer starting season 3.

[image: Beric S1] [image: Beric S3]

---

### Bloodraven:

Struan Rodger season 4. Max von Sydow season 6.

[image: Bloodraven S4] [image: Bloodraven S5]

---

### Leaf:

Octavia Selena Alexandru season 4. Kae Alexander season 6.

[image: Leaf S4] [image: Leaf S6]

---

### Night King:

Richard Brake season 5. Vladimir Furdik season 6. Furdik is also the one we see in human form.

[image: Night King S5] [image: Night King S6] [image: Night King Human]

---

### Dickon Tarly:

Freddie Stroma season 6. Tom Hopper season 7.

[image: Dickon 1] [image: Dickon 2]

---

### Lothar Frey:

Tom Brooke season 3. Daniel Tuite Season 6.

[image: Lothar 1] [image: Lothar 2]

---

### Rickard Karstark

Steven Blount Season 1. John Stahl starting season 2.

[image: Karstark 1] [image: Karstark 2]

---

### Selyse Baratheon

Sarah MacKeever season 2 (not credited). Tara Fitzgerald starting season season 3.

[image: Selyse 1] [image: Selyse 2]

---

[Source 1](http://www.thisisinsider.com/game-of-thrones-actors-roles-recast-2017-6) : [Source 2](https://mashable.com/2017/08/10/game-of-thrones-recasting/#B6V02iheMmqt)

Comment: Do we know why? Does it happen so much on other shows? Some of those recasts were really bad and looked completely different (e.g. The Mountain and Daario Narharis).

Comment: @EricDuminil Some were stand in extra's until the cast an actual actor e.g. Selyse. Some were the actors having scheduling conflicts e.g. Daario. Some were them wanting to recast themselves e.g. Tommen. I'd imagine 3ER and Leaf were recast for a change of direction.

Comment: Daario was the one that really got me. He looked like a completely different character - they didn't even try to match the hair/beard/etc to soften the jarring discontinuity.

Comment: @TimB If you look at the above images most of the recasts have changed completely, it's just more noticeable in Daario.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I think that was also partly because there was either a larger gap between the two appearing on screen (i.e. most had a season without the character before the new one appeared) or dramatic and recognizable costume (i.e. the mountain normally appeared in full armour) or a child growing older so larger changes are expected.

Comment: @TimB I agree Daario is the one most people notice, along with The Mountain. I just wanted to point out that when you actually look most of the recasts have changed the look of the character quite a lot.

Comment: @EricDuminil You also see that a lot of changes came between seasons after the character had only appeared in one or only a few. So the audience had a year or longer to forget what the character looked like.

Comment: @Skooba I started pretty late. I just had the time to eat a pizza between two seasons.

Comment: `see the other answer`, Dude, I'm super hurt.

Answer (score 74):

## [Ghost](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost)

[image]   [image]
<sup>[img 1 src](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/gameofthrones/images/7/70/Screen_Shot_2013-06-16_at_12.18.27_AM.png) | [img 2 src](https://i.cbc.ca/1.3078255.1431974030!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/16x9_1180/quigly-wolf.jpg?imwidth=720)</sup>

In Season 1, **Ghost** was played by a [Northern Innuit](http://www.dogbreedstandards.com/northern-inuit-dog/) pup (a variety of large wolf-like Dog) provided by the [Mahlek Northern Innuits](http://ww38.mahleknortherninuits.co.uk/gameofthrones.htm).

From Season 5 onward, **Ghost** was played by Quigly the real life wolf. Rescued and trained by trainer Andrew Simpson from [Instinct Animals for Film](http://www.instinctforfilm.com/wolves).

Comment: I'd forgotten Ghost even existed; guess I have something in common with the show runners then.

Comment: Not sure it is a recast if you have different actors because they are due to significant age differences. A pub is not a grown up wolf.

Comment: @TomTom It takes less than 4 years for a dog or wolf pup to reach adulthood.

Comment: And it takes significantly less than that to shoot the scenes of one season, I would imagine. Ups. You seriously suggest they WAIT UNTIL THE PUP GROWS UP? SERIOUSLY?

Comment: I mean, they recast Tommen for the same age difference thing...